# Get object with minimum value using extension method min()

Tags: c#, methods, min

list.Min() gets me the min value as integer. I want to get the object in List which has the min value for a certain property X. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [`MinBy`](https://github.com/amithegde/morelinq/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) in [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/amithegde/morelinq) - or I believe Reactive Extensions has something similar in `System.Interactive`:

```
var cheapestProduct = products.MinBy(p => p.Price);
```

If more than one item has the lowest value, the earliest one in the sequence will be returned.

Comment: @agent-j: I fixed it a minute ago :)

Comment: sorry Jon but I cant use MoreLINQ. I am not allowed to add a framework for a simple query...Therefore I wrote "using extension method min()" and not MinBy ;-) I have orderedBy now the p.Price and gaet that object to work with its properties.

Comment: @msfanboy: Any reason you can't just include a similar extension method in your own code? You could even take the exact same code so long as you include that code under your own licence. There's no need to order the results - which will be slower and less clear than a simple `MinBy` method.

Comment: ah my bad... I thought the MinBy is inside the MoreLINQ, now I saw its your extension method... Thanks I will have to ask first wether I can use 3rd party (you) code, then I return.

Comment: @msfanboy: It *is* inside MoreLINQ - MoreLINQ is an open source project.

Comment: I am not allowed to use open source :)

Comment: @msfanboy: Then implement it yourself - it's about 10 lines of code, and distinctly neater than using OrderBy, IMO.

Comment: Well I understand your code which is about 15 lines of code with security... checks, but how can I make/optimize your code to 10 lines? you are Jon Skeet the code machine :P ok seriously now, I can not rewrite your extension method having different code but doing the same so I cant use it. If your code would be bad... but its not improvable...