# use LINQ to find the product with the cheapest value?

Tags: c#, linq

Im learning LINQ and I want to find the cheapest product from the following list:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product> { 
                new Product {Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M, ID=1}, 
                new Product {Name = "Lifejacket", Price = 48.95M, ID=2}, 
                new Product {Name = "Soccer ball", Price = 19.50M, ID=3}, 
            };
```

I have come up with the following but somehow it feels like it is not the best way to do it:

```
var cheapest = products.Find(p => p.Price == products.Min(m => m.Price));
```

can you show me the right way to achieve this.

Comment: See this identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414052/get-object-with-minimum-value-using-extension-method-min

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `MinBy`:

```
public static TSource MinBy<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IComparable> projectionToComparable
) {
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence is empty.");
        }
        TSource min = e.Current;
        IComparable minProjection = projectionToComparable(e.Current);
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            IComparable currentProjection = projectionToComparable(e.Current);
            if (currentProjection.CompareTo(minProjection) < 0) {
                min = e.Current;
                minProjection = currentProjection;
            }
        }
        return min;                
    }
}
```

Just add this as a method in a `public static` class (`EnumerableExtensions`?).

Now you can say

```
var cheapest = products.MinBy(x => x.Price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could simply order them and take the first result, this is assuming you're after the `Product` object and not the `Price` value; like so.

```
var cheapestProduct = products.OrderBy(p => p.Price).FirstOrDefault();
var mostExpensiveProduct = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is `O(n log n)` where as `O(n)` is possible. In fact, the OP's solution is already `O(n)` it just has the downside that it has to scan the list twice. In fact, it is possible to scan the list exactly once, as if we were computing the minimum price. But instead, we keep track of the product with the minimum price: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10912887/45914

Comment: @Jaon: I don't see where OP has mentioned that he needs the fastest possible implementation. Maybe it's sufficient to use the easiest which is fast enough?!

Comment: @TimSchmelter, in that case why use `LINQ` at all. Would a simple `ForEach` not suffice then too? I think looking at performance is always good, sure we don't want to go crazy but keeping it in mind is not a bad habbit to get into.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Because LINQ's main advantage **is** readability. So actually a _"simple"_ `ForEach` in most cases is more difficult to maintain and understand than a simple LINQ query. But anyway, the `MinBy` approach is readable(if hidden in an extension method) **and** can be really faster.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: There's a really easy, straightforward `O(n)` algorithm that is easy to code, easy to understand, and easy to use. There is no reason to instead use an algorithm with worse algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by the price first and then select the first.

```
if(products.Any()){
    var productWithCheapestPrice = products.OrderBy(p => p.Price).First();
}
```