# c# dictionary get the key of the min value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

probably a simple one for you today but I'm currently going round in circles. Consider this scenario:

```
var tempDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
tempDictionary.Add("user 1", 5);
tempDictionary.Add("user 2", 3);
tempDictionary.Add("user 3", 5);

Console.WriteLine(tempDictionary.Min(x => x.Key) + " => " tempDictionary.Min(x => x.Value);
```

The above returns "user 1 => 3".

How would you go about returning the key with the lowest value in a dictionary? The output I'm after would look like this instead: "user2 => 3"

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good way to get the key of the highest value of a Dictionary in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805703/good-way-to-get-the-key-of-the-highest-value-of-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp)   (and in come the edits to the answers to reflect this)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

using [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview)

```
var keyR = tempDictionary.MinBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;
```

or

```
 var min = tempDictionary.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value < r.Value ? l : r).Key;
```

from [Highest value of a Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805703/good-way-to-get-the-key-of-the-highest-value-of-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was after in regular linq. Just waiting on stackoverflow so I can mark this as the answer I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: What happens when there are at least two keys with the same minimum value (same for the maximum condition)? In experimenting with this, I'm finding that the Aggregate returns the last min (or max) value found. How do you handle for two or more min or max values?

Answer (score 18):

```
var keyAndValue = tempDictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", keyAndValue.Key, keyAndValue.Value);
```

If your dataset is non-trivial in size, you might consider the MinBy extension in [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). [Here's an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10912887/14357) hosted on SO.

Comment: Thanks spender, thankfully the size of the list will be pretty trivial, but moreLinq looks like a useful tool to get to grips with. Thanks for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 4):

**Try this one :**
`var val = tempDictionary.OrderBy(k => k.Value).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(val.Key +" => "+val.Value);`

Comment: I think it's probably safer to blow up on the first line by using `First`, rather than leaving `val` possibly set to `null`. Otherwise a `null` check should be made prior to the call to `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is less efficient as it takes O(n log n) but choosing the minimum should be just O(n).

I think this is an easier way:

```
tempDictionary.Where(e => e.Value == tempDictionary.Min(e2 => e2.Value)).First()
```

using this you can even get all minimum values if you just remove `.First()`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I preferred not ordering the values of the dictionary, but simply find the min with a single iteration (ordering is > O(N)). You may need to guard against corner cases and similar.

```
    var s = String.Empty;
    var min = Int32.MaxValue;
    foreach (var item in tempDictionary) {
        if (item.Value < min){
            s = item.Key;
            min = item.Value;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s + " => " + min);
```