# Using linq to find the cheapest item in a list thats greater than 0

Tags: c#, linq

Im facing a problem with sorting lists where im trying to find the cheapest value. The sorting is not the problem, its the values returned that are the problem and the condition i want to meet.

Basically I may have 0 values in my results set, this is because these items have been temporarily put on hold and as such they dont hold a value but quotes still arrive for them.

The idea was to sort the results by total value and then take the first item in the list which in theory would be the cheapest.

```
void Main()
{
    GetCheapest();
}

public void GetCheapest()
{
    List<Car> numbers = new List<Car>
    {
         new Car() { Type="dearest",    Total = 990 },
         new Car() { Type="",           Total = 570 },
         new Car() { Type="",           Total = 907 },
         new Car() { Type="cheapest",   Total = 0 },
         new Car() { Type="",           Total = 333 },
         new Car() { Type="",           Total = 435 },
         new Car() { Type="",           Total = 435 }
    };

    //order ascending
    IEnumerable<Car> query = numbers.OrderBy( q => q.Total );

    //set the cheapest to be the first index in the sorted IEnumerable
    var cheapest = query.First();

    //output the cheapest
    Console.Write( cheapest.Type + " - £" + cheapest.Total + ", Winning!!" );

    //new line
    Console.WriteLine( Environment.NewLine );

    //output each one
    foreach( Car q in query )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( q.Type + " - £" + q.Total );
    }
}


//Quote Object
public class Car
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**In summary**
I would like to iterate through the returned list until I reach an index which holds a value greater than 0.

> The answer to the example given would be 333.

If anyone has any better ideas of doing this im open to trying them.

I have looked at these questions on SO so far which **dont** yield an answer:

[use LINQ to find the product with the cheapest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912819/use-linq-to-find-the-product-with-the-cheapest-value)

[Get object with minimum value using extension method min()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414052/get-object-with-minimum-value-using-extension-method-min)

Comment: I'm confused ... The code you posted already does this, right?  Are you looking for a better way?

Comment: @HaukurHaf Yes it does give the cheapest value which is 0, but 0 is not a value, anything above 0 would be the cheapest value.

Comment: Yes of course :-)  Then I'd just add a where statement to exclude values of 0 before ordering and then take the first one. EDIT:  Just like the answer by D Stanley below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something it would just be:

```
numbers.Where(c => c.Total > 0)
       .OrderBy(c => c.Total)
       .First();
```

or to chain to your existing query:

```
IEnumerable<Car> query = numbers.OrderBy( q => q.Total );

var cheapestCar = 
    query.Where(c => c.Total > 0)
         .First();
```

Comment: Clean and elegant, Thanks! Im going to keep the IEnumerable<Car> in because Id like to iterate through to output each value for comparison.

Comment: @KyleT Then you can just chain to that if you want - I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int cheapest = numbers.Where(c=>c.Total > 0).Min(c=>c.Total);
```

will get you the minimum price greater than 0 in the list.

The where clause removes anything with a total <= 0 from the list. The min call returns the smallest remaining value.

If you would rather have the whole object rather than just the price, use

```
var cheapest = numbers.OrderBy(c=>c.Total).First(c=>c.Total > 0);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the corresponding `Car` object, not the `Total` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That would also work, upvoted for your use of min.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a way to process an already sorted list of values:

```
IEnumerable<Car> query = numbers.OrderBy( q => q.Total );
```

skip all 0s, then take the first element:

```
var cheapest = query.SkipWhile(x => x == 0).First();
```

Comment: @pquest In my answer I was assuming that values were already sorted. You may have a look at the edit I made.

Comment: Shouldn't you skip when the value is 0, or better yet when it is <= 0.

Comment: @juharr You are right, It is the opposite from what I've written. Negative values are ruled out I think, since values represent prices.